# LaunchNavigator is not defined at Scope.$scope.getDirections

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I tried to access the map in my app but var launchNavigator function doesn't run. pls some one assist.

app.controller("YelpController", function ($scope, $cordovaLaunchNavigator) {

```
    $scope.getDirections = function(cafe){
        console.log("Getting directions for cafe");

        var launchNavigator = function() {
        //  console.log("Getting directions for raam");
        var destination=[
            cafe.location.coordinate.latitude,
            cafe.location.coordinate.longitude
        ];
            var source=[
                $scope.yelp.lat,
                $scope.yelp.lon
            ];

                launchNavigator.navigate(destination,source);

             };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this myself but try changing your call from launchNavigator.navigate(destination, source); to $cordovaLaunchNavigator.navigate(destination, source);